# Printing stderr with logging module

Tags: python, logging

I am using python `logging module`. With this logging module I used to print statements with logging.info func

But problem is that I am not getting stderr messages in the log file. Is there a way I can print stderr with logging module

Following code I am using

```
import logging

def initialize_logger(output_dir):
    '''
    This initialise the logger
    :param output_dir:
    :return:
    '''
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # create console handler and set level to info
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    handler = logging.FileHandler(output_dir, "w")
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

In the above code, I am sending only logging statements in the log. It means that I am not getting stderr in the same log file as logging file. Is there a way I can use the same file to send stderr. For example, If my code fails, then along-with logging messages it should also send stderr message.

Right now I don't know why this is happening but seems like my framework has suppressed stderr and stdin messages to print on the console.

Is there a way I can log stderr via logging module?

Comment: You mean when you would do `sys.stderr.write("message")`?

Comment: I mean with the above code, stderr is nowhere printed. Neither on the console, nor in the log

Comment: This question appears a bit malformed: where are the messages "to stderr" coming from? Your log file will **only** receive the messages that you emit via your logger `info()`, `debug()` etc. methods - anything else will go to their usual destination (`sys.stderr` and `sys.stdout` are special file handles, but have nothing to do with `logging`).  Can you please elaborate on what are you trying to do and what did you expect instead?

Comment: With the above code, you don't actually print/write/log anything, so it's unclear what you mean.

Comment: I edited the question. Please check and let me know if it is clear now

Comment: To reiterate Marco's comment: *only* logging statements (using the logging functions) are logged. `print`, `sys.stderr.write`, `sys.stdout.write` and others do not automatically use logging output.

Comment: How to do that if I want to log them in log file

Comment: Again: you use the log functions to log whatever you want to a log file.

Comment: You'd need to give a clear *example* of what you want to do.